# Using an if statement in Middleman erb view file

Tags: ruby, middleman

I am trying to figure out how to selectively show / hide a block of html in a Middleman erb view layout file based on a variable in the YAML.

So, in my markdown file I've got

```
---
DisableChooser: false
---
#some markdown
```

Then in the layout file, there is

```
<% if current_page.data.DisableChooser == "true" %>
<%= partial "layouts/sidebar" %>
<% end %>
```

Originally I just wanted it if it was set, but it doesn't seem to check the value no matter what I put there (except 0 or 1, which it seems to choose with - as in `if 0` / `if 1`)

I imagine I'm doing something stupid, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: The answer is putting the YAML is quotes, but if anyone wants to do an answer explaining that, I'll give them the answer for it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that simply making the YAML in quotes works! (though it seems happy not to do so with strings that are output to HTML)

```
---
DisableChooser: "false"
---
#some markdown
```